# php how to move up the directory until a specific file

Tags: php, regex, symfony, directory-structure

lets say i have a directory structure like this

```
____
|  Root
    |_____
       Folder1
    |_____
       Folder2
         |_____
            Subfolder2.1
            Subfolder2.2
                 |______
                    Subfolder2.2.1
```

if i wanted to move upwards from `Subfolder2.1` to the `Root` folder i would have to do `../../` and if i have to move from `Subfolder2.2.1` to `Root` i would have to do `../../../` is there a way in php or in regular expression to write ***an expression that goes back up the directory until it finds a specific file name*** (root)

currently in symfony framework i'm doing something like `$defaultTemplate = '::../../../../../app/Resources/views/'.$input->getOption('mytwigdest')` to create a template inside a directroy

ofcourse this only works for one level of folders not its subfolders or its parent folder, what expression do i need to put in instead of the `../` so that it goes up the directories until it finds a specific directory name

__ DIR __ and symfony's `$this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir')` would not work as it would give me the current file's path which is entirely different from where i'm creating a template using `$defaultTemplate`

Comment: Are numbers in directories `Subfolder2.2.1` used for only representing your problem or exist as part of the real directory's name?

Comment: just for explaining it to SO

Comment: imo, As the subfolders normally contain useful and identified things. i.e. log file, data files, etc. I just have a few defined constant to access them. i.e. `APP_LOG_DIR`, `APP_DATA_ROOT`, etc. They are setup by the 'application bootstrap'.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure why you need to go with such a way to solve your problem, this will calculate number of parent directories `../` to a custom directory. You only want to change the name. Here it is `Root`:

```
str_repeat("../", count(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , __FILE__)) - (1 + array_flip(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , __FILE__))['Root']));
```

Put all things together:

```
$defaultTemplate = '::'.str_repeat("../", count(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , __FILE__)) - (1 + array_flip(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , __FILE__))['Root'])).'app/Resources/views/'.$input->getOption('mytwigdest');
```

Comment: i like the use of php builtin functions, but still the `__FILE__ `gives the current file's address which i do not want i want to move upwards from a different folder not the current one. +1

Comment: Concise ways are welcome but sorry, there is no built-in function for this specific problem. @ptsdtriggered

Answer (score 0):

```
 include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/index.php');
```

Will always find the direct to root folder.  Note you need `/` after $_SERVER.

Comment: this results in creating a set of directories like `C > wanp64 > www > projectname` it actually thinks those are directories that need to be created XD this is same as using __ DIR __ or that symfony method i mention in the question